# Automatically add translate tags to Twig for Symfony translate component

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on the i18n of my website and all our templates are just plain old English. I'm look for a tool (Google didn't help) that can make adding translation tags semi-automatic.

So for example from an input template:

```
Hello {{ name }}
<a href="/logout">Log out</a>
```

It would make:

```
{% trans with {'%name%': name} from 'app' %}sayhello %name%{% endtrans %}
<a href="/logout">{% trans %}logout_text{% endtrans %}</a>
```

And YML:

```
sayhello %name%: Hello %name%
logout_text: Log out
```

Since someone needs to add the placeholder names for the translation, I imagine this would be some interactive program parsing Twig templates in the project.

Are you aware of anything like that?

Comment: Sorry, but questions asking to find tools/libraries/etc. are out of scope, that's why I vote to close this question. I am also not aware that such a tool exists.

Comment: Why are they out of scope?

Comment: As stated on the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Well that sounds like a nonsense rule.

Comment: I doubt there is such a tool. You guess you could have some success with regex.